# Message Collector first Message

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm using the`createMessageCollector`. It is collecting messages, but the problem is, that it is not getting the first message sent in the channel.

```
const filter = m => m.content.toLowerCase() === message.content.toLowerCase();
    const collector = message.channel.createMessageCollector(filter, { max: 1, time: 10000 })

    collector.on('collect', async collector => {
        console.log(collector.content)
    })

    collector.on('end', collected => {
        console.log(collected.size)
    })
```

Need help in getting the first message sent in the channel.

Comment: You mean `message`? That would be the message that triggered the messageCreate event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume that you want the message from the same channel, so I changed your filter a bit, but the filter needs to be passed into the collector like below:

```js
const filter = m => m.channel.id === message.channel.id
const collector = message.channel.createMessageCollector({
    filter,
    max: 1,
    time: 10000,
})
```

Answer (score -2):

It's as easy as [`collected.first()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/main/class/Collection?scrollTo=first).

Comment: I'm looking for a way, when someone enters a message, the collector should trigger and collect the value. But in my case, I'm using `messageCreate` method. So, first I need to send a message to initialize the collector. 

I'm thinking of how to trigger the collector without sending the first message.

Comment: just... fetch the channel and make a collector there?

Comment: @CrazyVolt ^^^^

Comment: In the `messageCreate` method?

Comment: @CrazyVolt no, wherever you need the collector

Comment: @CrazyVolt is your goal to get the first ever message in the channel? if so you would have to fetch them all and that's bad on the API